# psfrag prevents eps files (from Chemdraw) to be compiled with Latex->dvi

Tags: eps, rendering, psfrag, yap

I am moving to a new PC with an update of all programs. Setup is Win11 with Miktex 22.10/Winedt 11/gsview 5.0/Ghostscript 10.0.

Under the new setup, I suddenly have issues when compiling a document that contains eps figures that use `psfrag` to insert a running index into my figures.
As error message I get "Some postscript specials could not be rendered" when opening the preview dvi-file with yap.
This seems to apply to all eps files on the same page of the compiled document (even then ones that do not use psfrag), strangely enough, no matter what eps file I use.
Also, in the old setup (see below for details of my previous configuration) psfrag directly replaces the strings without showing "psfrag replacements" at the lefthand side of the figure. Not sure whether this might be relevant.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{psfrag}

%------------------------------------------------------------------
% Index creation for numbering of chemical formulas in graphs and in the text

\newcounter{verbindungen}
\newcommand{\Verb}[1]{\refstepcounter{verbindungen}\label{#1}}  %defining the index name and how to assign the number (with command \Verb)
\newcommand{\vref}[1]{{\bf \ref{#1}}}                           %defining the command of how to replace the placeholder with the index number (with command \vref)

%------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\author{Author}
\title{Trial and errors}
\maketitle

\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.3\baselineskip}

%-------------------------------------
%   Introduce placeholder indices
\Verb{08_C1} \Verb{08_C2} \Verb{08_C3} \Verb{08_C4}

%-------------------------------------

Die Wichtigkeit der räumlichen Struktur von Molekülen bei chemischen Interaktionen steht nicht erst seit dem Thalidomid-Skandal der 1950/60er Jahre im Fokus bei der Identifizierung, Herstellung und Anwendung einer Substanz. Die Eigenschaften von Konstitutions- und Stereoisomeren können sich drastisch unterscheiden -- selbst Enantiomere haben in einer chiralen Umgebung wie dem menschlichen Körper unterschiedliche Auswirkungen (s. Abb.).

\begin{figure} [h!]
\epsfig{file=08_C.eps, scale=0.70}
\end{figure}


Der Zugang zu Zielstrukturen mit der gewünschten Konstitution, Konfiguration und Konformation verlangt Methoden, deren Selektivität sich aus den Edukten mittels Substratkontrolle ergeben und welche durch die geschickte Wahl an Katalysatoren und Reagenzien verstärkt oder sogar überschrieben werden kann.\newline
Die Chemo-, Regio- und Stereoselektivität organischer Reaktionen kann entweder durch sterische Effekte, elektronische Effekte, oder die Kombination von beiden beeinflusst werden. Abbildung zeigt Beispiele von Umsetzungen, deren Selektivität oder Reaktivität entweder primär auf sterischen oder elektronischen Faktoren beruht: Die diastereoselektive Michael-Addition des Cuprats an das Enon \vref{08_C1} liefert mit hoher facialer Selektivität das Keton \vref{08_C2} mit einer $\alpha$-ständigen Methylgruppe. In der Tritylierung der C5-Hydroxygruppe im Glucosederivat \vref{08_C3} wird ausschließlich das an der primären Alkoholfunktionalität geschützte Kohlenhydrat \vref{08_C4} gebildet. Im Gegensatz zu diesen sterisch kontrollierten Umsetzungen wird die Geschwindigkeit der Verseifung von unterschiedlich substituierten Benzoesäureestern rein durch den elektronischen Einfluss des \emph{para}-ständigen Substituenten verändert. Je stärker der Akzeptor, desto schneller ist die Reaktion.

\begin{figure} [h!]
\centering
\psfrag{08_C1}{\vref{08_C1}} \psfrag{08_C2}{\vref{08_C2}} \psfrag{08_C3}{\vref{08_C3}} \psfrag{08_C4}{\vref{08_C4}}
\epsfig{file=08_C.eps, scale=0.70}
\end{figure}

Grundlegende sterische Effekte führen ebenfalls vor allem bei den Konformerengleichgewichten von Carbo- und Heterocyclen zur Präferenz einer bestimmten Struktur. Beispielsweise sind die relativen Energien verschiedener Konformere und Übergangszustände von Cyclohexan und Cyclohexen auf eine Kombination aus Winkelspannung, Torsionsspannung und van-der-Waaals-Abstoßung zurückzuführen (s. Abb.).

\begin{figure} [h!]
\centering
\epsfig{file=08_C.eps, scale=0.70}
\end{figure}

Die sterische Repulsion von axialen Gruppen in substituierten Cyclohexanen lassen sich im Vergleich zu den in Abbildung dargestellten Konformeren sehr leicht direkt spektroskopisch nachweisen: Das Gleichgewicht der Konformere mit jeweils axial und äquatorial-ständigem Substituent (K$_{eq}$) kann bestimmt und daraus der Unterschied in der freien Bildungsenthalpie $\Delta$G$^{o}$ berechnet werden. Dieser Energieunterschied wird in der Literatur üblicherweise als \emph{A-Wert} bezeichnet und wird oft als Näherungswert für den sterischen Anspruch einer funktionellen Gruppe herangezogen.

\end{document}
```

The corresponding eps-file for a trial can be found here: https://we.tl/t-Fid3A9zSPK

If you comment out the psfrag command in line 42, everything works.

I was dreading moving to a new computer - "never change a running system" - but unfortunately it became necessary.

Do you encounter the same issue? If so, how could it be fixed? If not, what might be the cause with my configuration?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

PS: The title page `\maketitle` is necessary - otherwise yap crashes - but that's another issue I have to tackle...

Things I have tried so far:

- Different eps files (from Chemdraw) all give the same result.
- The running index is not at fault, also gives the same error when manually replacing the strings with numbers
- with pdflatex the pdf file shows all figures correctly but the indices have not been replaced - the strings are still visible
- Works fine with Win 7 / Miktex 2.8 / gsview 4.9 / Ghostscript 8.64

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: `s error message I get "Some postscript specials could not be rendered" when opening the preview dvi-file with yap. `  that is not a problem just telling you yap can not handle pfrag, just ignoreor preview pdf rather than dvi you need latex/dvips/ps2pdf not pdflatex and not latex/yap.

Comment: not related but why are you still using `\epsfig` syntax??? it is a very thin wrapper around `\includegraphics`  produced in 1994 as a legacy compatibility layer for documents from the 1980s.

Comment: As my previous configuration could handle psfrag, I am somewhat at a loss why it no longer can. Regarding your second point - it is an excerpt from a book I started writing 15 years ago and just finished. So my knowledge of the most common packages is outdated as well. I am a "pure" user and have no understanding of the programming details behind it. Just never learned to code.